# tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory, but labels are from csv?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

Please tell me where I'm going wrong. I am working on the kaggle dog breed classification challenge and I want to try one-hot encoding vs label encoding. The images are not split in the images directory so I can not use 'inferred' with tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory, the labels are in a separate csv file that I put into a df (label_int).

```
cat_count = 120 #depth or the number of categories
oh_input = tf.one_hot(label_int, cat_count) #apply one-hot encoding
```

label_int is a list of all my labels in integer form, in the same order as my images in the directory. oh_input is a list of one-hot vectors.

```
batch_size = 32
img_height = 224
img_width = 224

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(train_dir,labels = oh_input,label_mode = 'categorical',validation_split=0.2,subset="training",seed=123,image_size=(img_height, img_width),batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(train_dir,labels = oh_input,label_mode = 'categorical',validation_split=0.2,subset="validation",seed=123,image_size=(img_height, img_width),batch_size=batch_size)
```

The error:

```
154 if kwargs:

155 raise TypeError(f'Unknown keywords argument(s): {tuple(kwargs.keys())}') --> 156 if labels not in ('inferred', None):

...

100 dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum 101 ctx.ensure_initialized() --> 102 return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype) TypeError: Cannot convert 'inferred' to EagerTensor of dtype int64
```

I have tried other datatypes in the tf.one_hot function and none of them working. I'm guessing I am just missing some fundamental syntax error.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory

I have also tried labels= *(a numpy array of integer values) with label_mode =int and that gave me another error. I also tried labels = None and it says 'Found 10222 files belonging to 1 classes.' so I'm not sure if I can add in the labels later to the fit function.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you could use keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator() class and then use flow_from_directory() or flow_from_dataframe() as it's functions depend on the case you are working on.

Comment: I was planning on doing that after looking into it a little more. But as I understand it,  ImageDataGenerator is specifically for augmenting the images before training. In the future if I do not want to do augment, I would still like to know how to be able to use image_dataset_from_directory. The tf API notes makes it sound like what I'm looking for is definitely possible.

Comment: but you could even not setting parameters for augmentation in ImageDataGenerator() and leave them to be set None, but If you wanna check out how could have been done only by image dataset from directory, change your strategy and make dirs and subdirs based on labels in csv file and then move images based on labels to the subdirs.